# Can’t make child in Qtreeview using QStandardItemModel

Tags: c++, qt

After reading some examples I am still missing here something. 
I have Qtreeview for view and QStandardItemModel for the data interface, also using QSortFilterProxyModel subclass but I don't know if its relevant. 
This is my logic:
First I create the model with the QWidget as the parent:

```
QStandardItemModel m_model = new QStandardItemModel(0,4,parent);
then setSourceModel(m_model)  for the widget
```

Set the treeview with QSortFilterProxyModel. something like this:

```
GroupProxyModel = new GroupSortFilterProxyModel;
GroupProxyModel->setDynamicSortFilter(true);
setSourceModel(createSubjectModel(parent));

ui.treeView_mainwindow->setModel(GroupProxyModel);
ui.treeView_mainwindow->setSortingEnabled(true);
```

Then later I fill the first row like this:

```
QList<QStandardItem *> items;
items.insert(0,new QStandardItem("Test 0"));
items.at(0)->setEditable(false);
m_model->insertRow(0,items);
```

Until now every thing working fine and I see the row with the data. But when I like to 
    add child to the row like this:

```
QModelIndex parentQModelIndex = m_model->item(0,0)->index();
m_model->insertRows(0,1,parentQModelIndex);
m_model->insertColumns(0,1,parentQModelIndex);
QModelIndex indexB = m_model->index(0, 0, parentQModelIndex);
m_model->setData(indexB,"Child test",Qt::DisplayRole);
```

But I don't see the child, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not how QStandardItemModel works - to add a child, call appendRow(s)/insertRow(s) on the parent QStandardItem:

```
QStandardItem* child = new QStandardItem( tr("Child test") );
...
QStandardItem* parentItem = m_model->item( 0, 0 );
parentItem->appendRow( child );
```